# How to use \usepackage[parfill]{parskip} in memoir class?

Tags: memoir, paragraphs

I would like to have a blank line between my paragraphs. In this way, I have decided to use :

```
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
```

However, it does not work with the memoir class.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}
\section
lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.
Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae
ornare odio metus a mi.
\end{document}
```

Indeed, I get this error :`/test.tex:6: LaTeX Error: Option clash for package parskip. []`

Does anyone can help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: Look at section 3.1.1 in the manual of `memoir`. Simply use `\nonzeroparskip` as the `parskip` package is not compatible with `memoir`. But first read carefully what the author of `memoir` says about it.

Answer (score 10):

You don't use the `parskip` package in `memoir`: it's listed among the ones that the class emulates (page xxix of the manual).

In section 3.3.1 it is explained how to set a nonzero `\parskip`, but I'd like, first, to quote from the manual:

> **3.3.1 Paragraphs**
>   In traditional typography the first line of a paragraph, unless it comes immediately after a chapter or section heading, is indented. Also, there is no extra space between paragraphs. Font designers go to great pains to ensure that they look good when set with the normal leading. Sometimes, such as when trying to meet a University’s requirements for the layout of your thesis, you may be forced to ignore the experience of centuries.
>
> If you like the idea of eliminating paragraph indentation and using extra interparagraph space to indicate where paragraphs start and end, consider how confused your reader will be if the last paragraph on the page ends with a full line; how will the reader know that a new paragraph starts at the top of the following page?

You can use

```
\nonzeroparskip
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\nonzeroparskip
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

If you're not satified by this setting, you can use

```
\abnormalparskip{12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
```

or any other length you want (don't forget the stretch and shrink parts) instead of `\nonzeroparskip`.

[image]

Comment: I like the macro name: `\abnormalparskip` :)